# Is the Double Fine Adventure Documentary publicly available?

Tags: broken-age

Being lame, I missed out on backing the Double Fine Adventure, which would go on to produce *Broken Age*.  I am still curious about some of the behind-the-scenes stuff, a la *Indie Game: The Movie*, but I can't tell if there is anywhere to buy the episodes.  The [2PP page](http://www.2playerproductions.com/projects/double-fine) points me to the DFA [Slacker-Backer page](http://www.doublefine.com/dfapay/), which is now out of commission.

[Episode one (available on YouTube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMbQRnoxZ2E) was interesting, but I want more!

Comment: [Related meta-post](http://meta.arqade.com/questions/8389/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Double Fine Adventure documentary series about the making of Broken Age is (as of yesterday) available for public purchase. Currently, it can be purchased separately or in a variety of bundles with the game here: http://brokenagegame.com/buy/